# How to correctly stop the TimerTask

Tags: java, spring

So basically I have a task with a delay that kills a VPN pod. I don't want to have a running pod when it's not needed.

The Desired behavior is when the service receives a request(REST) it cancels the existing task and creates a new one with further delay.

In my solution I use *thread.stop()* to cancel my task which has been deprecated for a while.

```
...

var VPN_TIMER_THREAD_NAME = "vpn-timer";
for (var thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    if (thread.getName().equals(VPN_TIMER_THREAD_NAME)) {
        // Interrupted doesn't work for me
        thread.stop();
    }
}

var timer = new Timer(VPN_TIMER_THREAD_NAME);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // New Transaction for EM
              TransactionStatus tx = VpnServiceImpl.this.txManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
              try {
                var vpnToUpdate = VpnServiceImpl.this.em.find(Vpn.class, vpn.getId());
                doTearDown(vpnToUpdate);
                VpnServiceImpl.this.txManager.commit(tx);
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                log.error("Tear Down Error {}.", e.getMessage());
                VpnServiceImpl.this.txManager.rollback(tx);
              }
            }
          }, this.vpnProperties.delay());
...

private VpnStatusS2SDto doTearDown(Vpn vpn) {
    log.debug("In the tear down");
    this.client
        .pods()
        .inNamespace(this.kubeProps.getNamespace())
        .withLabel("app", "vpn-gateway")
        .withLabel("app.kubernetes.io/component", "vpn")
        .delete();

    entity.setModifiedDate(Instant.now());
    this.em.persist(entity);
    return mapper.toVpnStatusDto(entity);
}
```

When I'm changing to thread.interrupt() the doTearDown method is invoking more than once if I make more than one request.
With thread.stop it "kills" the previous task and creates a new one, indeed the tear down has been invoked only once.

I'm using Spring Boot.

Is there any way to implement that behavior?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you want to call the TimerTask's cancel method. Keep a reference to it (global by all means - better than traversing all stacks) when you create it and call cancel. That will not stop it if it is running, but it will prevent it from starting again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer from [ewramner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612030/ewramner) I found the solution. It works as expected. Every new request cancels the existing task and creates a new one.

I've created the nested task class:

```
private class ShutDownTask extends TimerTask {

    private final Vpn vpn;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager txManager;
    private final EntityManager em;

    ShutDownTask(Vpn vpn, PlatformTransactionManager txManager, EntityManager em) {
      this.vpn = vpn;
      this.txManager = txManager;
      this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TransactionStatus tx = this.txManager.getTransaction(new 
        DefaultTransactionDefinition());
        try {
            var vpnToUpdate = this.em.find(Vpn.class, this.vpn.getId());
            doTearDown(vpnToUpdate);
            this.txManager.commit(tx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            this.txManager.rollback(tx);
        }
    }
}
```

In my service class:

```
@Service
public class VpnServiceImpl {
    ...
    private final PlatformTransactionManager txManager;
    private final EntityManager em;
    private ShutDownTask shutDownTask;
    ...

    if (this.shutDownTask != null) {
      this.shutDownTask.cancel();
    }

    var timer = new Timer("vpn-timer");
    this.shutDownTask = new ShutDownTask(vpn, this.txManager, this.em);

    timer.schedule(this.shutDownTask, this.vpnProperties.delay());

    ...
}
```